# Syntax Error: Unexpected EOF while parsing?

Tags: python, parsing, average, eof

I'm doing a simple little average calculator.

```
def avg():
    sumSoFar = 0
count = 0
numCount = 0

while numCount != "":
    numCount = eval(input("Please enter a number or press <enter> to quit: "))
    sumSoFar += numCount
    count += 1


print("The average of these numbers is: ", sumSoFar/count)
```

And I keep getting the error:

```
numCount = eval(input("Please enter a number or press <enter> to quit: "))
File "<string>", line 0

Syntax Error: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Any idea whats the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I assume this happens when you "press <enter> to quit", since that will result in `input` raising a `SyntaxError` because there is no expression to evaluate.

[`input(prompt)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`. Consequently, it is not correct to `eval` it; if the input line is (a string representing) a number, then `input` will return a number, and `eval` of a number is a `TypeError`. However, since you say that you're getting a `SyntaxError`, I conclude that your input starts with a blank line.

I really don't think `input()` is the function you want to be using, but if you're going to use it, and particularly if you want the loop to terminate when an exception is raised, then you really need to call it within a `try` block so that you can catch the exception. On the other hand, using `raw_input` will allow you to test whether you received an empty string, but you need to do that before you call `eval` on the string, so putting the test in the `while` condition won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
sumSoFar = 0

count = 0

numCount = input("Please enter a number or press <enter> to quit: ")

while numCount != "":

    sumSoFar += eval(numCount)

    count += 1

    numCount = input("Please enter a number or press <enter> to quit: ")



print("The average of these numbers is: ", sumSoFar/count
```